# PDO Prepared Statements - NULLs

Tags: php, sql, null, pdo

I have a delete query that I'm running, but just realized that this doesn't work when `$user_id` is null (which happens in certain cases).

```
$id = 1;
$user_id = null;
$delete = $sql->prepare("
    DELETE FROM
        `game_player`
    WHERE
        `id` = ?
    AND
        `user_id` = ?
");
if ($delete->execute(array(
    $id,
    $user_id,
));
```

Is there any work around other than having different queries for when the value is null, since apparently the only way to have the where work properly is with `user_id IS NULL` instead of `user_id = NULL`...

Comment: I would think IS NULL is clean cut, and more effectively

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM
    `game_player`
WHERE
    `id` = ?
AND
    (`user_id` = ? OR ? IS NULL)
```

Be careful to parenthesis properly when mixing *and* with *or* operators.

If `$user_id` isn't really php type null, but say, an empty string, you should modify the above as such:

```
...
AND
    (`user_id` = ? OR ? = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick or statement solves the problem. Change this bit of code.

```
$delete = $sql->prepare(
    "DELETE_FROM 'game_player' where 'id'=? and 'user_id'=?;");
if ($delete->execute(array(
    $id,
    $user_id
));
```

Into something more like the following.

```
$delete = $sql->prepare(
    "DELETE_FROM 'game_player' where ('id'=? and 'user_id'=?) 
                                  or ('id'=? AND 'user_id' IS NULL)");
if ($delete->execute(array(
    $id,
    $user_id,
    $id
))) { /* success */ }
```